# Some congratulations phrases for birthday?

Tags: grammar, syntax

Hi I want to write a congrats message to my Japanese friend and I want to tell him this:

```
  Happy birthday

  I wish you so many more wonderful experiences 

  and have a lot of fun this day
```

Obviously the first line will be:

```
  お誕生日おめでとう
```

And the second line will be:

```
 もっと素晴らしいことがあるといいです
```

And the third line something like this:

```
  そして楽しい日を過ごしてね
```

So I think that the first and third lines are relatively correct, but I really have my doubts on the second line. What do you think? Is there another way to say the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I think もっと(たくさん)素晴らしいことがあるといいです isn't unnatural and it is literally translated as "もっとたくさん素晴らしい経験(体験)をしてね."

The other option I came up is"もっとたくさん素晴らしい出来事があるといいね.".

Comment: So といい it's actually used for wishing to oher people?

Comment: Yes, it is often used but ね,な,ですね usually attach to it.

Answer (score 1):

This may just be my personal style of speaking, but for the second line I'd say

> 今年素晴らしい経験がたくさんありますように

or

> 今年が素晴らしい体験いっぱいの一年になりますように

Also, for the third line I'd say 「楽しい一日」 instead of just 「楽しい日」, but that's something minor.

Answer (score 0):

```
もっと素晴らしいことがあるといいです
```

It does not sound odd, but your translation is incorrect... In English, it is:

> I hope more wonderful things happen (to you).

I would translate:

> - もっと素晴らしい経験(体験)がありますように (prayer)
> - もっと素晴らしい経験(体験)ができるといいね